# Align block-level element and paragraph element by baseline

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a header aligned with a body of text by baseline, but this seems to prove surprisingly hard. I've been toying with different methods but can't seem to find the perfect solution. Here's an example of what I'm after:

[image: example]

```
<h2>XxMmxX</h2>
<p class="right">
    I saw for the first time the earth's shape. I could easily see the shores of continents, islands, great rivers, folds of the terrain, large bodies of water. The horizon is dark blue, smoothly turning to black. . . the feelings which filled me I can express with one word—joy.
</p>
```

Style:

```
h2 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 190px;
    top: 30px;
}
.right {
    margin-left: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

I would like to have the baseline of 'XxMmxX' aligned with the baseline of the text.

Some notes:

- The header is right-aligned and has a fixed width
- The header uses a bigger font-size than body
- I want them to be perfectly aligned, this means not just setting a top of some px and having it almost aligned. (this page will be printed and this will definitely be noticeable)

Comment: can you post code instead of an image?

Comment: You could fiddle with the `line-height` property until they match up. If you increase your `p` line-height slightly, it'll MOSTLY match up to your floating headers.

Comment: @Nathan I tried the fiddling approach, and as you say it'll _mostly_ line up, but unfortunately this needs to be perfectly lined up (gets converted to PDF and printed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a table, and use `vertical-align: baseline;`

Comment: Well, yeah, that works. But I'd rather not use tables for layout purposes (and the example shows no tabular data).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, without a table:
First I use a `<div>` instead of `<p>`:

```
<h2 class="left">XxMmxX</h2>

<div class="right">
    I saw for the first time the earth's shape. I could easily see the shores of continents, islands, great rivers, folds of the terrain, large bodies of water. The horizon is dark blue, smoothly turning to black. . . the feelings which filled me I can express with one word—joy.
</div>
```

I use `float` to put the `<div>` beside the `<h2>`. And the alignment trick is done by setting known font sizes, like `1em` to `<div>` and `1.5em` to the `<h2>`. This way you need to move down the `<div>` by a known amount, in this case `0.5em`. Moving down is done with `position/top` (you could also use a margin-top). Here it is:

```
.left {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;

}

.right {
  font-size: 1em;
  float: left;
  width: 20em;  
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I've put this in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6veD4/ and it's not aligned, although this does make it possible to align the lines in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I may have something that's kinda close. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEh95/2/).

HTML:

```
<span class="textblock">
  <h2>XxMmxXx</h2>

  <span class="right">
    I saw for the first time the earth's shape. I could easily see the shores of continents, islands, great rivers, folds of the terrain, large bodies of water. The horizon is dark blue, smoothly turning to black. . . the feelings which filled me I can express with one word—joy.
  </span>

</span>
```

CSS:

```
.textblock {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 15em;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

It seems that `vertical-align: text-top` may be what you want, but it requires everything to be inline. Combined with `display:inline-block` you may be able to get something close to what you need. You'll probably have to fiddle with the width and margin of the `.right` class to adjust to your layout.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. And it's indeed close, but it should be perfect. This comes down to the last note again. The baselines aren't aligned, so if I were to increase the header font-size, everything is out of alignment again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a table layout, nor `vertical align`. Set both elements to use the same `line-height` and align the top of the elements.  If you're picky about getting the text to rest on a baseline, use `position:relative; and top:FOOpx` to move the text up and down.